# Data image with CSP

Tags: web-application, content-security-policy

I am trying to get an image that is within JavaScript to work with our CSP. I have [read](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94993/is-including-the-data-scheme-in-your-content-security-policy-safe) that using `data:` (even in `img-src`) is an XSS risk so I'm trying to avoid that.

Because it is called from within a .js file I'm not sure how to get it working properly. I've tried using the `sha256-base64-value` value outlined here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src

I have tried the sha256 hash of the base64 value, and the sha256 of the downloaded image (created from the base64 value). E.g. within nginx CSP:

> img-src 'self' fda3f82c94742ce8331f51c2bb0e7f45c7da67e1d8618dc345b77a8dcfc6686e-iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAYAAAAsEj5rAAAAU0lEQVR42u3VOwoAMAgE0dwfAnNjU26bYkBCFGwfiL9VVWoO+BJ4Gf3gtsEKKoFBNTCoCAYVwaAiGNQGMUHMkjGbgjk2mIONuXo0nC8XnCf1JXgArVIZAQh5TKYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=;

and

> img-src 'self' 3c1ed8cea465b0a63ee09ce0a1013be0e482752f91c32fcd59b3cae2627f764f-iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAYAAAAsEj5rAAAAU0lEQVR42u3VOwoAMAgE0dwfAnNjU26bYkBCFGwfiL9VVWoO+BJ4Gf3gtsEKKoFBNTCoCAYVwaAiGNQGMUHMkjGbgjk2mIONuXo0nC8XnCf1JXgArVIZAQh5TKYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=;

I get the following error in Chrome's console:

> Refused to load the image 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAYAAAAsEj5rAAAAU0lEQVR42u3VOwoAMAgE0dwfAnNjU26bYkBCFGwfiL9VVWoO+BJ4Gf3gtsEKKoFBNTCoCAYVwaAiGNQGMUHMkjGbgjk2mIONuXo0nC8XnCf1JXgArVIZAQh5TKYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

How can I get this data image working with a CSP securely?

Comment: I’m no expert. But have you tried using the Sha-256 of the entire script? Not just the base64 value

Comment: *"I have read that using data: (even in img-src) is insecure so I'm trying to avoid that."* - could you please provide a reference to this claim so that one can see if what is claimed is actually relevant in your use case?  Apart from that, it is not clear of what you actually did. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can reproduce your problem and help you. Note that a hash is only documented to be usable for scripts or styles, not for images.

Comment: @keithRozario Thanks but I've tried that with no luck.
Steffen Thanks, updated as per your comment.

Comment: there's no need to SRI a data-url-based image, because it comes from your server; if you can't trust your own server, there's no point in SRI or a CSP.

Comment: @vegedezozu: like I said, hashes are not for images but only for style and script. And I cannot see anything in your reference which says that using data URI as `img-src` is a problem. Note for example [that answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/167244/37315) which says (and provides a source for it): *"MDN calls out explicitly that <img> embedded SVGs cannot execute Javascript"*. Thus I don't see how allowing data-URI as  `img-src` should be a XSS risk or other problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that answer refers explicitly to SVGs not images per se, my image is a PNG so didn't think it was relevant. So is everyone saying adding "data:" to my CSP is okay so long as it is in an img-src?

Comment: @vegedezozu: the answer referred explicitly so SVG since SVG is the only image format which can actually contain script, PNG, JPEG etc can't do this. And, if used in the context of an `img` tag [polyglot attacks](http://www.thinkfu.com/g00/blog/gifjavascript-polyglots) don't work either since the browser explicitly wants to interpret the content as image. In other words: Allowing `data:` for `img-src` within the CSP is fine.

Comment: Here's a good post on how XSS can inject script into your site from data-uri: https://www.paladion.net/blogs/bypass-xss-filters-using-data-uris  this vulnerability has less to do with trusting your own server and more to do with trusting other peoples servers which your site has external scripts to - or even trusting the internet proxy a user is on - for example pretend "fee internet" at airports are really good at stealing user data and doing man-in-middle